# Google Maps: how do i change the default zoom?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-embed

I've created a simple [real-estate website](http://bangalore-property-buy.com) with a Google-map via Google-'My Maps'.

The site has a photo-album with a bunch of pics. I've used some of these pics to create 'My Maps' - a Google mapping thingy which allows you to add pics to a private map just for your web-site.

The map renders on my website just fine, except, the markers are all scrunched up. How do I give that map a higher 'Zoom' so they don't look so cluttered.

Note: I've read http://marcgrabanski.com/jquery-google-maps-tutorial-basics/
but here, **he starts from scratch** by loading the default map for a particular lat/long using

> var burnsvilleMN = new GLatLng(44.797916,-93.278046);

and then adds all the markers:

> marker = new GMarker(point);

**I have an existing 'My Maps' map** https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zMUI-z11i1mw.k7KikFgwemt0 that I need to modify (the center is set) from within 'My Maps'.

Comment: GLatLng and GMarker are from the deprecated and turned off [Google Maps Javascript API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference?csw=1).  That version should **not** be used for new code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried minZoom and maxZoom properties from [google map options](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#ZoomControlOptions)
with default of 0

```
var mapOptions = {
      center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);
```

for embedded map 
use **z** insted of **zoom**

```
https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zMUI-z11i1mw.k7KikFgwemt0&z=6
```

Comment: well that's the problem! you are using 'new' whereas i'm using <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zMUI-z11i1mw.k7KikFgwemt0" height="400px" width="600px"></iframe> I don't want to start from scratch and create a minty fresh map object

Comment: have you tried adding "&z=18" at the end of the map link?

Comment: sweet, many thanks! that worked. would be nice if you could point me to where that's documented.

Comment: @RaviSwamy If that helped then vote up and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding &z=18 to the end of the map link works well. You can adjust the zoom by increasing or decreasing the number.